# iOS 8 - presentViewController flicker and delay

Tags: ios8, presentviewcontroller, visual-glitch

i have the following problem since upgrading to iOS 8:

**Additional informations:**

- No storyboard
- No xib files
- No NavigationController (Because i don't want a title bar)
- viewController switching with "`presentViewController:nextViewController animated:NO completion:nil`" (Works perfectly with iOS 7).
- rootViewController was set in AppDelegate
- Dissmissing the viewController works (still) perfectly

As already mentioned above i switch the view controllers in my app with the "presentViewController" method without any animations. 
Since iOS 8 there is a short delay after calling presentViewController, which results in a shortly shown black screen (seems like its the window background) and on the new iPhone 6 with a oversized background image.

I already tried out:

**1.** The presentViewControllerCall in:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

**2.** The UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen transition style

**3.** Implementing the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol

But nothing worked for me.

Maybe somebody here has an idea... It is really frustrating :-(

Regards

Comment: how do you load the view in your new view controller?

Comment: I use the normal view controller life cycle. In the "viewDidLoad" of the new view controller my additional views will be created (added as subview).